# Gradle multi-project recursive dependency tree

Tags: java, android, dependencies, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Project tree is as follows:

```
- APPLICATION
--- CORE_LIBRARY
----- SUBLIBRARY1
----- SUBLIBRARY2
----- SUBLIBRARY3
```

I'd expect `CORE_LIBRARY` to declare own dependencies, and `APPLICATION` to just include CORE_LIBRARY with all its dependencies.

**APPLICATION/CORE_LIBRARY/build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile project('SUBLIBRARY1')
    compile project('SUBLIBRARY2')
    compile project('SUBLIBRARY3')
}
```

**APPLICATION/CORE_LIBRARY/settings.gradle**

```
include 'SUBLIBRARY1', 'SUBLIBRARY2', 'SUBLIBRARY3'
```

So far so good. Now I'm able to run 'gradle assemble' from **APPLICATION/CORE_LIBRARY** directory.
But Then comes the problem, with *just* including CORE_LIBRARY to APPLICATION

**APPLICATION/build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile project('CORE_LIBRARY')
}
```

**APPLICATION/settings.gradle**

```
include ':CORE_LIBRARY'
```

This does not work, we need to reference `':CORE_LIBRARY:SUBPROJECT1', ... etc` from **APPLICATION/settings.gradle**.

Can't we just include all subproject dependencies ?

Comment: You can only have a single `settings.gradle`.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser can I include dependencies from another settings.gradle or from project itself?

Comment: There's no feature to include another `settings.gradle`, but you can script `settings.gradle` however you like. Not sure what you mean by "from project itself".

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser I mean, I need to merge them. In a way dependencies worked in ANT. I want to get rid of library dependencies in my main project. So I can just plug the library in and don't need to link all library subprojects/sublibraries into application `settings.gradle`